# Angular 2 Object in Object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, rest, angular

How can I create a class named `Bill` which have simple properties like `string and number` & another property which is an `Object` of another Class `Customer`.

I want the Bill `json` object `bill: Bill` look like this:

```
  bill = {

     id: "",
     usage : "",
     total : "0",

     customer : {
        customerFirstname :"",
        customerLastname :"",
     }

  }
```

This object was in `AngularJS` correct but not in `Angular2`.

Customer Class:

```
 export class Customer{
    customerFirstname: string;
    customerLastname: string;
    constructor (){
    }
 }
```

and Bill Class:

```
import {Customer} from '../customer/customer.model'; 
 export class Bill {

  id : string ;
  usage: string;
  total: number;
  customer : Customer;
  constructor (){
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `extends`

Ref: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

For your example:

```
 export class Customer {

    public customerFirstname: string;
    customerLastname: string;
    constructor() {
    }
   }

export class Bill{

    id: string;
    usage: string;
    total: number;
    customer: Customer;
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

use:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Bill } from '../models/Animal';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    bill: Bill = new Bill();

    constructor() 
    {
        console.log(this.bill.customer.customerFirstname)
     }

    ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: I have extend, but it's not work in `html` by displaying `{{ bill.customer.customerFirstname }}`

Comment: `{{ bill.customerFirstname }}` u just need to do this. @Manu

Comment: it dont work: ERROR: `customerFirsname do not exist in Object bill`

Comment: Oh. Let me check.

Comment: Updated my answer @Manu

Comment: with the `extends` and `super();` its dont change nothing:: the properties like `{{bill.customerFirstname}}` are always null or ignored

Comment: Oh. I just went through ur JSON obj. U may now try out the example. Sorry about the inconvience.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no need for classes in this case. Just use interfaces, you'll get your desired behavior with them, so your interfaces:

```
export interface Bill {
  id : string ;
  usage: string;
  total: number;
  customer : Customer;
}

export interface Customer{
    customerFirstname: string;
    customerLastname: string;
}
```

You can instantiate a new `Bill` like so:

```
bill: Bill = <Bill>{};
```

and if when you want to type your data, be that JSON,

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "usage":"usage",
  "total":"0",
  "customer":{
     "customerFirstname":"firstname",
     "customerLastname":"lastname"
  }
}
```

TS:

```
this.myService.getBill()
  .subscribe(data => {
     this.bill = data;
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something in the lines of this:

```
export interface ICustomerProperties {
   customerFirstname: string;
   customerLastname: string;
}

export class Customer {
   customerFirstname: string;
   customerLastname: string;

   constructor (properties: ICustomerProperties) {
      this.customerFirstname = properties.customerFirstname;
      this.customerLastname = properties.customerLastname;
   }
}

export interface IBillProperties {
   id: string;
   usage: string;
   total: string;
   customer: Customer;
}

export class Bill {
   id: string;
   usage: string;
   total: string;
   customer: Customer;

   constructor (properties: IBillProperties) {
      this.id = properties.id;
      this.usage = properties.usage;
      this.total = properties.total;
      this.customer = properties.customer;
   }
}

let customer = new Customer({ customerFirstname: 'first', customerLastname: 'last' });
let bill = new Bill({ id: '1', usage: '', total: '', customer: customer});
```

Comment: @ArgOn  I have extend, but it's not work in html by displaying `{{ bill.customer.customerFirstname }}` and I get the error : `customerFirsname do not exist in Object bill`

Comment: How do you instantiate your `Objects`?

Comment: `bill = new Bill()`

Comment: Yeah so your `Bill` `Object` will not have a `customer`.. You have to either pass it to the `constructor` or set it after you've created the `Object`.

Comment: how can i pass it to the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

This is because attribut `customer` not have been instanced in `Class Bill`
And all variables have to be instanced by declaration

```
  Customer Class:

 export class Customer{
   customerFirstname: string = '';
   customerLastname: string = '';
   constructor (){
 }
}
```

and

Bill Class:

```
 import {Customer} from '../customer/customer.model'; 
 export class Bill {

   id : string = '' ;
   usage: string = '';
   total: number = 0;
   customer = new Customer;
   constructor (){
   } 
 }
```